# Detecting mobile in an isomorphic reactjs

Tags: express, mobile, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

How should I implement detecting mobile in my reactjs + express? I used [mobile-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect) to determine if mobile but first I implemented it with `const md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent)` but I remembered `window` doesn't exist when it's server loaded. The example in express section should work because that's the only place I could access `req` but how do I pass it in my react app to be used afterwards?

**UPDATE**

```
// app.js

...
import { routes } from './routes';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

...
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // routes is our object of React routes defined above
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, props) => {
  if (err) { // something went badly wrong, so 500 with a message
    res.status(500).send(err.message);

  } else if (redirectLocation) { // we matched a ReactRouter redirect, so redirect from the server
    res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);

  } else if (props) { // if we got props, that means we found a valid component to render for the given route
    const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
    const store = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore)(reducer);

  ...
const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3003;

server.listen(port);
server.on('listening', () => {
  console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});

// client-render.js
import { routes } from './routes';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router onUpdate={() => {scrollTop(); handleNotifs(store)}} routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

// routes.js
import AppComponent from './components/app';
import IndexComponent from './components/index';
...

const routes = {
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: IndexComponent,
    name: 'home'
  }, {...}]
}
```

Comment: How did you implemented routing in your server and client side? There is a lot of approaches to solve this problem but you have provide more information about your current architecture.

Comment: I'll update my question for the configs but bear with me, I don't know if I posted the right configs.

Answer (score 4):

I accomplished exactly what you are requiring by making my routes module become a function that takes the user-agent. It then simply returns an array or nested routes. Here's an example...

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = (userAgent) => {
  const md = new MobileDetect(userAgent)
  if (md) { // not sure on the syntax of MobileDetect?
    return {
      // return mobile routes
    }
  } else {
    return {
      // return desktop routes
    }
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match({ routes: routes(req.headers['user-agent']), location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, props) => {
    // continue as normal
  }
}
```

**client-render.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router onUpdate={() => {scrollTop(); handleNotifs(store)}} history={browserHistory}>
      {routes(navigator.userAgent)}
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

On a side note, using this approach we are able to also pass in the auth cookie to the routes so the `onEnter` methods can redirect if the route is behind login.

Hope this helps! BTW React-Router is the best!! I got to meet the creators in NYC and they're top notch.

Comment: On second thought, this would only solve route selection based on mobile... where you wanting to simply pass `isMoble` down to the app from the server rendering? You can always pass it into the component as props during the `renderToString` and do the same thing in the client render too.

Comment: This worked for me. I generated different chunks for mobile and desktop website. Using this, i was able to load dynamically only mobile components in mobile device and only desktop components in desktop device.